# Python, reading ID3 tags from m4a files

Tags: python, id3, m4a

I have a large collection of m4a files, all with ID3 tags for genre, artist, and titles. What I would like is to be able to read these tags and store them as strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such common tasks, ready-made libraries almost always exist. A quick Google search for `python m4a` yields:

- [Mutagen](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [tinytag](https://github.com/devsnd/tinytag)